# SQL Server CONVERT function doesn't convert '&'

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql table with a field varbinary(max) that contains string in it. I'm using varbinary because input in that field could potentially be larger than maximum char for nvarchar.

I'm trying to display the content of that field as a string by using

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(max), Folders)
```

The problem that I have is, if content has '&' it in it doesn't get converted properly. 
It displays like that "`Test &amp; test`".

Is there any other way to convert?

Comment: CONVERT is used to coerce/cast data types. It is NOT intended for de-entitizing html/xml.

Comment: Thanks. What could I use to do what I need to do?

Comment: varbinary(max) and varchar(max) are the same size

Answer (score 0):

if the content could potentially be larger than the maximum of nvarchar, why do you want to convert it to nvarchar?

Try using

```
Replace(Convert(nvarchar(max), Folders), '&amp;','').
```